# Problema con MySQL remoto

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

Muy buenas tardes, espero que estén bien, les quiero comentar el problema que estoy teniendo a ver si a alguien le paso y consiguió la solución.

Tengo un programa hecho en visual .NET y este lo que hace es tomar información de las tablas de mi base de datos en SQLServer guardarla en un DataTable y por partes subirla al servidor web. El sistema es

BDSQLServer 'tienda' --------> DataTable -----------> BDMySQL 'tienda'

El programa funciona perfectamente en mi PC, en mi casa, pero cuando lo llevo al cliente y lo pruebo al intentar hacer la conexion a la BD MySQL, me devuelve el siguiente mensaje

> "Unable To Connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts"

El hosting no creo que bloquee  la IP ya que tengo abierta la base de datos para cualquier IP.

Probé diferentes tipos de cadenas de conexiones y ninguna la toma. Recordemos que en mi PC funciona perfectamente el programa, pero cuando lo llevo tira ese error.

Lo último que pensé fue en los puertos, pero fue una idea, no probé nada al respecto.

Comment: Lo básico es hacer un telnet al puerto de mysql, para descartar que sea un tema de red o de firewall.

Comment: Por lo que hable con el hosting, hicimos ping al servidor remoto y éste no envía ni recibe nada. Me dijo que el proveedor esta bloqueando la red. Hay alguna manera de que pueda omitir el bloqueo?

Comment: Podría ser del firewall ¿que tipo de panel de control tienes el el hosting? si es una configuración del sistema da igual que mysql esté configurado para aceptar cualquier ip.

Comment: Sí, la verdad no sé. El servidor que bloquea la IP tiene configurado un firewall del gobierno, y siento que si voy no me van a dar interés. Por eso quería saber si hay alguna manera de activar lo que haya que activar yo mismo... muchas gracias